# What are the IP addresses used by google app script?

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc

We have an app script projects that connect to our own MySQL database, we need to whitelist the IP of the Google app script to allow the connection.

Sometimes it's working, sometimes not so I think it is related to the IP used by the app script. We authorized all of the IPs from https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt but we still have errors sometimes.

What IPs are we also need to authorize?

Comment: You should be able to connect to your DB if you have white-listed all those IPs. Can you share the error you are getting? About `Sometimes it's working, sometimes not` are you changing anything between both situations? Also, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Iamblichus thanks for your answer, yes sometimes it's working and sometimes we get error "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username, and password." without changing any of code

Comment: Is there a way to reliably reproduce this? If that's the case, I'd suggest fielding a bug report at Google Issue Tracker https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#bugs.

Comment: @lamblichus thank you, it is the same bug as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241819492 . The way to reproduce it is to have an app script project which connects to an external(not on google cloud) MySQL server, sometimes the database connection fails and sometimes it's working and we don't know why because we haven't changed anything from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This seems to be a bug.

This has been previously reported at Google Issue Tracker:

- [JDBC Still Receiving Error "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241819492)

Anyone affected by this, consider [starring the referenced issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of it and to help prioritize it.